# MySQL JOIN query to join tables based on multiple cells and output to PHP

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have two tables in MySQL, one table contains details of wines, the second table contains details of boxes with columns that link to the ID of the wines table for each bottle that is in the box.

Eg. :

Wines
.ID
.Name
.Year
.Description

Boxes
.BoxID
.Name
.Bottle1
.Bottle2
-> ...
.Bottle12

so if I have a wine box which has 6 bottles in it, the fields for .Bottle1 thru .Bottle6 will contain the ID of the bottle from the Wines table.

I want to run a SELECT query in PHP that joins these two tables and outputs the following in my webpage:

Box-XXX
"Bottle of wine example1"
"Bottle of wine example2"
"Bottle of wine example3"
"Bottle of wine example4"
"Bottle of wine example5"
"Bottle of wine example6"

and if the box only has one bottle of wine it would display

Box-XXX
"Bottle of wine example1"

--EDIT--

I am attempting the following code which is not working...

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    include("dbconnect.php");
    $box_sql="SELECT a.*
            FROM box a left join
        WineID b1 on a.bottle1=b1.WineID left join
        WineID b2 on a.bottle2=b2.WineID left join
        WineID b3 on a.bottle3=b3.WineID left join
        WineID b4 on a.bottle1=b4.WineID left join
        WineID b5 on a.bottle1=b5.WineID left join
        WineID b6 on a.bottle1=b6.WineID left join
        WineID b7 on a.bottle1=b7.WineID left join
        WineID b8 on a.bottle1=b8.WineID left join
        WineID b9 on a.bottle1=b9.WineID left join
        WineID b10 on a.bottle1=b10.WineID left join
        WineID b11 on a.bottle1=b11.WineID left join
        WineID b12 on a.bottle1=b12.WineID left join
        where (b1.WineID is not null or 
                b2.WineID is not null or
                b3.WineID is not null or
                b4.WineID is not null or
                b5.WineID is not null or
                b6.WineID is not null or
                b7.WineID is not null or
                b8.WineID is not null or
                b9.WineID is not null or
                b10.WineID is not null or
                b11.WineID is not null or
                b12.WineID is not null)";
    if($box_query=mysqli_query($dbconnect, $box_sql)) {
        $box_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($box_query);
    ?>
<h1><?php echo $box_rs['boxnumber']; ?></h1>
    <?php do { ?>
        <div class="item">
        <a href="index.php?page=item&stockID=<?php echo $box_rs['WineID']; ?>">
        <p><?php echo $box_rs['Name']; ?></p>
        </a>
        </div>
        <?php
        } while ($box_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($box_query));
        ?>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

-----------EDIT-----------

Describe Wines output below=

```
Field       Type           Null     Key     Default     Extra   
WineID      int(4)         NO       PRI     NULL    auto_increment
categoryID  int(1)         NO       NULL    
Name        varchar(100)   NO       NULL    
Winery      varchar(30)    NO       NULL    
Year        varchar(4)     NO       NULL    
Country     varchar(20)    NO       NULL    
Region      varchar(30)    NO       NULL    
ABV         varchar(6)     NO       NULL    
bottlesize  varchar(6)     NO       NULL    
Grape       varchar(100)    NO      NULL    
Notes       varchar(2046)   NO      NULL    
ReadyEst    varchar(15)     NO      NULL    
Picture     varchar(100)    NO      NULL    
Price       varchar(10)     NO      NULL
```

DESCRIBE box output is below =

```
Field   Type    Null    Key     Default     Extra   
boxID   int(11)     NO  PRI     NULL    auto_increment
boxnumber   varchar(10)     NO      NULL    
year    varchar(4)  NO      NULL    
size    varchar(2)  NO      NULL    
bottle1     varchar(3)  NO      NULL    
bottle2     varchar(3)  NO      NULL    
bottle3     varchar(3)  NO      NULL    
bottle4     varchar(3)  NO      NULL    
bottle5     varchar(3)  NO      NULL    
bottle6     varchar(3)  NO      NULL    
bottle7     varchar(3)  NO      NULL    
bottle8     varchar(3)  NO      NULL    
bottle9     varchar(3)  NO      NULL    
bottle10    varchar(3)  NO      NULL    
bottle11    varchar(3)  NO      NULL    
bottle12    varchar(3)  NO      NULL
```

Comment: This post shows no research, this site isn't meant to be a code-request platform. There are many, many tutorials on running MySQL queries through PHP. Here's one example to start you off: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: ok well thanks for that.

Comment: For others - I have been trying the following query which is returning errors  $box_sql="SELECT a.*
   FROM box a left join
  WineID b1 on a.bottle1=b1.WineID left join
  where (b1.WineID is not null or ...

Comment: Perhaps you can update your question with the code you're using along with the current error, then it's easy for us to review your code and error and suggest edits.

Comment: sorry, trying to figure out the posting formatting etc. thanks.

Comment: @Chris, you should probably revise your database design, it seems like there would be a better way to do this as far as I can see, these 12 left joins will be incredibly expensive... Could you please run `DESCRIBE WineID; DESCRIBE box;` and report the results? That way I could try helping you figure out a more suitable design.

Comment: @FMashiro thanks very much, I have edited the post and included the DESCRIBE output.

Comment: @Chris I've added my answer with a new table structure that could fix your proble, let me know if that works for you or if you need help!

Comment: @FMashiro thanks very much. wrt to the Wine_In_Box are you suggesting that there will be a row for each combination of box and wine? eg. if WineID 3, 4, 5 are in BoxID 1, there will be three rows: ID1 = (1, 3), ID2 = (1, 4) and ID3 = (1, 5) ??

Comment: @Chris yes that's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I have a possible solution for your "problem"

Try this structure:

Wine Table:

```
Field       Type           Null     Key     Default     Extra   
WineID      int(4)         NO       PRI     NULL    auto_increment
categoryID  int(1)         NO       NULL    
Name        varchar(100)   NO       NULL    
Winery      varchar(30)    NO       NULL    
Year        varchar(4)     NO       NULL    
Country     varchar(20)    NO       NULL    
Region      varchar(30)    NO       NULL    
ABV         varchar(6)     NO       NULL    
bottlesize  varchar(6)     NO       NULL    
Grape       varchar(100)    NO      NULL    
Notes       varchar(2046)   NO      NULL    
ReadyEst    varchar(15)     NO      NULL    
Picture     varchar(100)    NO      NULL    
Price       varchar(10)     NO      NULL
```

Box table:

```
Field   Type    Null    Key     Default     Extra   
boxID   int(11)     NO  PRI     NULL    auto_increment
boxnumber   varchar(10)     NO      NULL    
year    varchar(4)  NO      NULL    
size    varchar(2)  NO      NULL
```

Wine_In_Box table:

```
Field   Type    Null    Key     Default     Extra   
id      int(11)     NO  PRI     NULL    auto_increment
boxID   int(11)     NO          NULL    
wineID  int(11)     NO          NULL
```

Now what you'd do is make a number of wines, and then create a box.
To fill the box you insert into Wine_In_Box table like so:

```
INSERT INTO Wine_In_Box (boxId, wineID) VALUES (1, 1);
```

Then when you want to retrieve the contents of the box, you run this query:

```
SELECT wid.*, w.*, b.* FROM Wine_In_Box wid LEFT JOIN Wine w ON w.WineID= wid.wineId LEFT JOIN Box b on b.boxID = wid.boxID WHERE boxId = ?;
```

This query will return all the info on all the wines in the box, which you can select by box. 
You could also change the where clause to get multiple boxes at once by using an `IN` clause.

Comment: I think I'm getting a bit lost on the last query - table is created, but the query fails. `SELECT wid.*, w.* FROM Wine_In_Box wid LEFT JOIN Wine w ON w.id = wib.wineId WHERE boxId = ?;`  is returning `#1054 - Unknown column 'w.id' in 'on clause'`

Comment: @Chris my bad, I put the wrong column name, should work now

Comment: thanks mate. I think I have it now - there's another typo in the code wib.wineId should be wid.wineId I think. Just ran it against boxId 2 and correct data came back. Will continue testing. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: @Chris my bad, long day...  That indeed is a typo! Let me fix that for you!

Comment: you've been a big help! Final thing - to display ALL boxes and all wine within them you suggest using the `IN` Clause. This works for example   `SELECT wid.*, w.* FROM Wine_In_Box wid LEFT JOIN Wine w ON w.WineID= wid.wineId WHERE boxId IN ( 2, 0) ;` but how do I display all rows without specifying each boxId individually?

Comment: There is no real good way to do this in pure mysql... unless you want an absolutely monstrous query. I suggest doing that in whatever language your application is built in, such as PHP or C# or whatever you chose, if you do, then the best thing you could do is select all the boxes, and then loop over those and query the wines per box, that way you'll have to make more database calls but you'll also be able to have readable code.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks, I will enter a loop in PHP! Cheers.

Comment: one last thing! I also want to bring down the boxnumber value from the Box table. The current query brings boxID but not boxnumber. What do I need to add to the SELECT string to include this?

Comment: @Chris I've just edited the answer again and it will now select the box as well :)